# Converting rectangular points into polar coordinates

Tags: c#

The problem I'm having is not finding the distance but finding the radians with Atan() and converting it to degrees.

```
using System;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        double xCoord =0, yCoord=0 ;       
        //accessing methods
        getUserInput(ref xCoord, ref yCoord);
        CalulatePolarCoords(ref xCoord, ref yCoord);
        outputCords( ref xCoord,  ref yCoord);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }//End Main()

    static void getUserInput(ref double xc, ref double yc) 
    {
    //validating input
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" please enter the x cororidnate must not equal 0 ");
            xc = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("please inter the y coordinate");
            yc = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if(xc <= 0)
    Console.WriteLine(" invalid input"); 
        }
        while (xc <= 0);
            Console.WriteLine(" thank you");

    }

   //calculating coords
    static void CalulatePolarCoords(ref double x , ref double y) 
    {
        double r;
        double q;
       r = x;
       q = y;
        r = Math.Sqrt((x*x) + (y*y));

        q = Math.Atan(x/y);

    x = r;
    y = q;
    }
    static void outputCords( ref double x, ref double y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" The polar cordinates are...");
        Console.WriteLine("distance from the Origin {0}",x);
        Console.WriteLine(" Angle (in degrees) {0}",y);
        Console.WriteLine(" press enter to continute");

    }
}//End class Program
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [`Atan2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan2.aspx) here.

```
q = Math.Atan2(y, x);
```

To convert to degrees multiply by `180/Math.PI`.

This will give you a result in the range -180 to 180. If you want it in the range 0 to 360 then you will have to shift any negative angles by 360.

I also strongly recommend that you do not return your polar coordinates in the same parameters that you used to pass in cartesian coordinates. Make your function like this:

```
static void CalculatePolarCoords(double x, double y, out double r, out double q)
```

Your `outputCoords` method also uses `ref` parameters incorrectly. Only use `ref` parameters for values that are passed into a method, modified, and then need to be passed back to the caller.

Comment: problem solved thankyou i was using 180/2*Math.PI instead of 180/Math.PI

Comment: To convert Atan2 results from -180...180 to 0...360 you merely need to shift by 180, not 360. A 360 degree shift would give you the range of 180...540. You need only to shift by 180 degrees:
q=(Math.Atan2(y,x)*180.0/Math.PI+180.0);
(using 180.0 vs 180 to remove any posssible conversion overhead).

Comment: @RichardRobertson No, that's not so. It's true that adding 180 gets you values in the right range, but the values are the wrong values. You need to do exactly what I say, add 360 to any negative values. You only shift the negative values, and you have to shift them 360 because otherwise you are changing the value. Remember that angles around a circle are compared for equality modulo 360.