# How can i generate a Polar co ordinate from Cartesian co ordinate in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, math

I want to make a program which will generate Polar Co ordinate from given Cartesian Co ordinate. But I found some programs which can return accurate result for 1st Co ordinate only, the result for 2nd, 3rd and 4th is always inaccurate.I think I need to customize for input x and y. If x and y both are positive, call a program; If both are negative, call another program ...
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting rectangular points into polar coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868708/converting-rectangular-points-into-polar-coordinates)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example